# C++ Converting MIDI Note ID in a note

Tags: c++, audio

I have a Midi keyboard that when plugged in my program i can red the values of each pressed if but i have been having difficulties into finding an appropriate method to convert each Note ID into a specific note.

the key id jumps from 128 to 640 to 1152 to 1408 it increases for each key i press.

this are some ways that i have tried to convert the id to notes but none have been able to produce the scale that i wanted.

```
FTYPE CSscaleConvert(const int noteID)
{
    double d12th = pow(2.0, 1.0 / 12.0);
    //noteID = noteID * 0.01;
    //return 12 * log2((noteID / 100) / 440.0);
    return 0.256 * pow(d12th, noteID);
    //return 440 * log2(noteID * 0.01 - 69) / 12;
    //return noteID * 0.256;
    //return noteID;
}
```

Comment: How are you reading and parsing the note on/off events? Remember that the data is in two bytes, where each byte have a special meaning (key and velocity, respectively). Also remember that each byte only uses *seven* bits for the note id and velocity.

Comment: wcout << "Velocity is " << HIWORD(dwParam1) << endl; //velocity
wcout << "Key ID is " << LOWORD(dwParam1) << endl; //keyID

Comment: i get the LO and the HI of the bite of the id and the speed

Comment: If you use the Windows [`HIWORD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms632657(v=vs.85)) and [`LOWORD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms632659(v%3dvs.85)) macros, then they retrieve a **16-bit** word from a 32-bit double-word. The Midi protocol is **byte** based. You *have* read [the specifications](https://www.midi.org/specifications)?

Comment: I'm quite new to this side of programming I have read some of the specifications but I could not really find any specifics online if you could send a reference to some sources I would be really appreciated

Comment: See my previous comment for a link to the official specifications and references from the MIDI association.

Comment: I have been going trough it but I cannot seem to find the exact place where it tells about the note id they only seem to go up to 255

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For anyone else that might encounter this I previosuly used this to try to acess the data 
wcout << "Velocity is " << HIWORD(dwParam1) << endl; //velocity
wcout << "Key ID is " << LOWORD(dwParam1) << endl; //keyID

but this was the correct way to do it

HIBYTE(dwParam1) << endl; //NoteNumber i think?
LOBYTE(dwParam1) << endl; //Velocity i think?